# How do I create a Sagemaker training job with my own Tensorflow code without having to build a container?

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to define a Sagemaker Training Job with an existing Python class. To my understanding, I could create my own container but would rather not deal with container management.

When choosing "Algorithm Source" there is the option of "Your own algorithm source" but nothing is listed under resources. Where does this come from?

I know I could do this through a notebook, but I really want this defined in a job that can be invoked through an endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bruno has said you will have to use a container somewhere, but you can use an existing container to run your own custom tensorflow code.

There is a good example [in the sagemaker github](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/tensorflow_script_mode_quickstart/tensorflow_script_mode_quickstart.ipynb) for how to do this.

The way this works is you modify your code to have an entry point which takes argparse command line arguments, and then you point a 'Sagemaker Tensorflow estimator' to the entry point. Then when you call fit on the sagemaker estimator it will download the tensorflow container and run your custom code in there.

So you start off with your own custom code that looks something like this

```
# my_custom_code.py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def build_net():
    # single fully connected
    image_place = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28*28])
    label_place = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None,])
    net = tf.layers.dense(image_place, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    net = tf.layers.dense(net, units=10, activation=None)
    return image_place, label_place, net


def process_data():
    # load
    (x_train, y_train), (_, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

    # center
    x_train = x_train / 255.0
    m = x_train.mean()
    x_train = x_train - m

    # convert to right types
    x_train = x_train.astype(np.float32)
    y_train = y_train.astype(np.int32)

    # reshape so flat
    x_train = np.reshape(x_train, [-1, 28*28])
    return x_train, y_train


def train_model(init_learn, epochs):
    image_p, label_p, logit = build_net()
    x_train, y_train = process_data()

    loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
        logits=logit,
        labels=label_p)
    optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(init_learn)
    train_step = optimiser.minimize(loss)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for _ in range(epochs):
            sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={image_p: x_train, label_p: y_train})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_model(0.001, 10)
```

To make it work with sagemaker we need to create a command line entry point, which will allow sagemaker to run it in the container it will download for us eventually.

```
# entry.py

import argparse
from my_custom_code import train_model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument(
        '--model_dir',
        type=str)
    parser.add_argument(
        '--init_learn',
        type=float)
    parser.add_argument(
        '--epochs',
        type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    train_model(args.init_learn, args.epochs)
```

Apart from specifying the arguments my function needs to take, we also need to provide a `model_dir` argument. This is always required, and is an S3 location which is where an model artifacts will be saved when the training job completes. Note that you don't need to specify what this value is (though you can) as Sagemaker will provide a default location in S3 for you.

So we have modified our code, now we need to actually run it on Sagemaker. Go to the AWS console and fire up a small instance from Sagemaker. Download your custom code to the instance, and then create a jupyter notebook as follows:

```
# sagemaker_run.ipyb
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow

hyperparameters = {
    'epochs': 10,
    'init_learn': 0.001}

role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()
source_dir = '/path/to/folder/with/my/code/on/instance'
estimator = TensorFlow(
    entry_point='entry.py',
    source_dir=source_dir,
    train_instance_type='ml.t2.medium',
    train_instance_count=1,
    hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
    role=role,
    py_version='py3',
    framework_version='1.12.0',
    script_mode=True)

estimator.fit()
```

Running the above will:

- Spin up an ml.t2.medium instance
- Download the tensorflow 1.12.0 container to the instance
- Download any data we specify in fit to the newly created instance in fit (in this case nothing)
- Run our code on the instance
- upload the model artifacts to model_dir

And that is pretty much it. There is of course a lot not mentioned here but you can:

- Download training/testing data from s3
- Save checkpoint files, and tensorboard files during training and upload them to s3

The best resource I found was the example I shared but here are all the things I was looking at to get this working:

- [example code again](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/tensorflow_script_mode_quickstart/tensorflow_script_mode_quickstart.ipynb)
- [documentation](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/README.rst)
- [explanation of environment variables](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-containers#list-of-provided-environment-variables-by-sagemaker-containers)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible as you may refer from [this part](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms.html) on SageMaker documentation. A container is needed for providing the capability to run with any language and framework.

The algorithms that are listed in training job creation, are the algorithms you can create in SageMaker -> Training -> Algorithms. But, it's necessary to define a container, which is a specification of how you can do training and predictions. Even if you don't build a container, you will refer to an existing one (using a built-in algorithm) or you will be using an algorithm from marketplace wich someones built that using an image.

I believe you could build an image that attends your needs parting from an existing one.

After you build the image, you can easily use it to automate your training/prediction jobs from lambda. [Here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_training_job) is an example.

Also, you can provide as many input channels to your container as you need to load data, in theory, you can pass a channel that refers to a script that you want to load while your container starts. But is an idea that I've just had, depending on your scenario, could be worth a test. Normally, you could have an image which you could customize during the docker build process. So, if have several different scripts, you can create only one image and just parameterize it to use a custom script.

- [Here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-container) you can find a custom image that uses Tensorflow.
- [Here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/advanced_functionality) are listed a lot of examples of building different containers for several frameworks, also, Tensorflow.

I hope it helps, let me know if need more info.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps you, but you can make use of Tensorflow estimators which is a like an inbuilt container from AWS. You need a training script and requirements.txt file which will contain the dependencies that you may need. You can follow this link for more information [Sagemaker TensorFlow estimators documentation](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/tensorflow/sagemaker.tensorflow.html)